# How to open mysql backend

Tags: kali-linux, mysql, phpmyadmin

I just installed mysql-server with `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`.
How can I open the webinterface now from the browser? I did not found anything in the [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/MySQL/).

On windows with xampp I just had to open `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` however, this is not working on my kali linux.

How can I open the backend?

Answer (score 2):

phpMyAdmin is a tool written in PHP to help you administrate a MySQL/MariaDB database server. The XAMPP development suite that you have installed on your Windows system already install and include all the required components and dependencies for both the MySQL database server and the phpMyAdmin application.

As you already installed the MySQL database server in your system, now you can install the `phpmyadmin` package by running the command below

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

The installation process will ask you a few questions in order to configure your installation correctly.

1. Choose **apache2** when asked for the server selection. Hit "SPACE", "TAB", and then "ENTER" to select **apache2**.
2. Select **yes** when asked whether to use `dbconfig-common` to set up the database.
3. You will be prompted for your database administrator's password.
4. You will then be asked to set and confirm a password for the `phpMyAdmin` application itself.

Finally, it is necessary to enable the `php5-mcrypt` module by running the command below

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

After that, you will need to restart the Apache Web Server service for changes to take effect by running the command below and then visit the `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` URL from your local browser to access phpMyAdmin.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Another easy solution is to uninstall the `mysql-server` package that you installed previously and install the XAMPP development environment in your Linux system from its official webpage at https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Comment: I followed all steps, but no page loads.

Comment: Did you restarted the Apache server before trying to visit phpMyAdmin? Did you get any error during the process?